# How to write this xpath in testcafe

Tags: testcafe

How to write the below xpath in Testcafe ?

//div[@id=‘test_1’]/preceding::input[1]

Tried everything nothing worked. Need to select first preceding input element to the div . Above selector is xpath but how to write it in css selector for Testcafe

Answer (score 0):

XPath selectors are not built into TestCafe, but you can implement a simple helper method to use them.

Please refer to the following help topic to learn [how to use XPath selectors in TestCafe tests](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/tree/master/examples/use-xpath-selectors).